# Is it possible to view posts and pages on the homepage of a wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Currently, On my blog homepage, only posts are visible. But I want to view both the posts and pages on the same homepage as shown in the image below.

[image]

How is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are expected to have researched your issue and made a good attempt to solve it before posting a question. If you still have specific issues, you can post a specific question with details of the error and what you have tried so far. including your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help.

Answer (score 2):

you can loop it.

Just do a loop for posts:

```
<!-- Start post loop here -->
<?php $query = new wp_query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => '3' ) ); ?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
<!-- Start post template here -->
<div><a aria-label="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
<!-- End post template here -->
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<!-- End post loop here -->
```

And a loop for pages:

```
<!-- Start page loop here -->
<?php $query = new wp_query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => '3' ) ); ?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ): while ( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
<!-- Start page template here -->
<div><a aria-label="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
<!-- End page template here -->
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<!-- End page loop here -->
```

gl.